# Finding Fourier series by evaluating sum of infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I have a function which is defined as 
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\cos(x)  & \text{for $|x| \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$} \\
0 & \text{for $|x| \in ]\frac{\pi}{2},\pi[$}
\end{cases} $$
and I want to show that the corresponding Fourier series is 
$$ \frac{1}{\pi} + \frac{\cos x}{2}+\frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{4k^2-1}\cos(2kx).$$

I know that $c_0 = \frac{1}{\pi}$ and that $c_1 = c_{-1} = \frac{1}{4}$. I have also been given 
$$ c_n =
\begin{cases}
0  & \text{for $n$ odd, when $n \neq \pm 1$} \\
\frac{1}{\pi} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{4k^2-1} & \text{for $n=2k$, for $k \in \mathbb{Z} $}
\end{cases}$$

So far, I have started by writing the series as
$$ \frac{1}{\pi} + \frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{4k^2-1}e^{i2kx},$$ and used $e^{i2kx} = \cos(2kx)+i\sin(2kx)$ to obtain
$$ \frac{1}{\pi} + \frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{4k^2-1}\left(\cos(2kx)+i\sin(2kx)\right) \\= \frac{1}{\pi}+\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{4k^2-1}\cos(2kx) + \frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{4k^2-1}i\sin(2kx). $$
What I need to show from here is $\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{4k^2-1}i\sin(2kx) = \frac{\cos x}{2}$, and I would have the series I'm trying to arrive at.
Is this approach correct? If so, how can I compute this last sum?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using the definition of the Fourier series, we have $$f(x)=c_0 + \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{i 2\pi nx}$$
Using the information given, we can decompose this sum into $$f(x)=c_0+c_1e^{i2 \pi x}+c_{-1}e^{-i2 \pi x}+\sum_{n \ odd, \ n\ne\pm1} c_n e^{i 2 \pi nx}+\sum_{n \ even} c_n e^{i 2 \pi nx}=1/\pi \ + c_1e^{i2 \pi x}+c_{-1}e^{-i2 \pi x}+\sum_{n \ even} c_n e^{i 2 \pi nx}$$
Noticing that $c_n=c_{-n}$, we can further simplify the equation into $$f(x)= 1/\pi \ + c_1(e^{i2 \pi x}+e^{-i2 \pi x}) \ + \ \sum_{n \ even, \ n > 0} c_n(e^{i2 \pi nx}+e^{-i2 \pi nx})$$
With the identity $e^{i2 \pi nx}+e^{-i2 \pi nx}=2 \ cos(nx)$ and plugging the formulas for $c_1$ and $c_n$, we can get the desired Fourier series.